# Socet recv hangs when server crashes

Tags: sockets

I am working on client server program using sockets on Windows and MAC and currently facing a issue where client call recv blocks forever when server program crashes/killed using task manager. I send some data to server and asynchronously wait for reply using recv. This reply will come from server after some time which can not be determined. 
I was expecting an error from recv when other ends of socket dies. Not sure how to handle this situation.

Suggestions ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Set a read timeout with `setsockopt()` and the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option, setting it to some sensible value.

Comment: Or use `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()` to wait for inbound data with a timeout, and only call `recv()` if there is something actually waiting to be read (which includes a graceful end-of-stream closure by the peer).

Answer (score 0):

Your recv should not hang (but instead indicate a closed connection) if you are using TCP and the peer socket gets properly closed and if the communication between both systems is working (no broken cable etc). In UNIX the socket gets properly closed by the kernel even if the process crashes or gets killed, but I don't know about the behavior of Windows in this case.

recv will still hang if you are using UDP for communication, because there is no explicit connection close.

Comment: You should get an end of stream, not an error. But it is possible for the sending *host* to fail in such a way that even that isn't sent.

Comment: Yes, but the main thing is that recv will not hang any longer. And yes, the sending host might fail completely but in this case the communication between both systems would not be working any longer. If the host crashed no socket close will be done and if the hosts comes up later again it will not know about any sockets which might still be open at the other end. There are things like timeouts or so_keepalive which might be used to detect this - but at the moment it is not even clear that the OP is using TCP at all for communication (timeouts will of course work with UDP too).

Comment: 'peer socket gets properly closed' - I think that the OP is more worried about the case where this does not happen.  In such cases, the default result with TCP is that the half-closed connection hangs forever, waiting for data that will never come.

Comment: At least on UNIX a socket gets properly closed even if the process gets killed, which is what the OP is worried about. Like I said, I don't know if Windows behaves the same but I would actually expect it. Again - it is very hard to speculate as long we don't even know what kind of communication protocol (TCP, UDP) the OP is using.